# When do the circuits of a matroid have a connected intersection graph?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matroid-theory

When does a matroid $M$ have a set of circuits $\mathcal{C}$ with a connected intersection graph i.e. when is the graph $G$ with$V(G)=\mathcal{C}$ and adjacencies $\{A,B\}\in E(G)\iff A\cap B\neq\emptyset$ connected?

This is equivalent to charactering the matroids with a partial ear-decomposition i.e. the matroids with circuits that can be indexed $C_1,\ldots C_n$ so we get that $\forall 0<i\leq n\exists j<i:C_i\cap C_j\neq\emptyset$ (where note this indexing is not necessarily injective i.e. there might exist $i\neq j$ with $C_i=C_j$)

---

Suppose we call matroids with this property special now if two matroids $M_1$ and $M_2$ are special and some circuit in $M_1$ is not disjoint to some circuit in $M_2$ then $M_1\oplus M_2$ is also special, with that said then what do "special" matroids look like? Is there a simple way to characterise these?

Comment: I don't see why the two questions you posed are equivalent. The first seems to be saying that the intersection graph of circuits has no isolated vertices, which is different from it being connected.

Comment: @SamHopkins made a slight error, updated it

Comment: Here's a first stab: evidently the matroid itself must be connected. I don't know if that's sufficient.

Comment: (Actually I guess there could be a connected component which has no circuits, i.e., a unique base.)

Comment: Your two conditions are still not equivalent.  Your first condition is saying that the intersection graph has a Hamiltonian path, while the second condition is saying it is connected.  I answered the connected version below.

Comment: @Ethan Is that condition about the graphic matroid right? For instance, a unicycle graph has a single circuit, so the intersection graph is connected, but it is not 2-edge connected.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt if its $2$-edge connected and a unicycle graph then it is a cycle graph, no?

Comment: @Ethan Yeah, but that doesn't contradict what I'm saying. I mean that a unicycle gives an example of a graph with your property that is not 2-edge connected. (Maybe your 'iff' is meant to be an 'if'? Actually I'm not sure about that either, e.g. consider the wedge of 2 circuits at a single point. It's 2 edge connected, but the circuit graph consists of two isolated points.)

Comment: @LorenzoNajt Sorry havn't slept in a while, you are correct. I also updated the condition on the indexing so it should be when is there a walk in the intersection graph hitting every vertex which is equivilent to connectedness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This holds if and only if $M$ has at most one connected component which contains a circuit.  Clearly, the intersection graph of circuits is disconnected if $M$ has two connected components which each contain a circuit.  For the other direction, suppose that $M$ has at most one connected component $N$ which contains a circuit.  If $M$ has at most one circuit, then clearly the intersection graph of circuits is connected.  Otherwise, let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be distinct circuits of $M$.  Note that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are circuits of $N$. Choose $e \in C_1$ and $f \in C_2$.  Since $N$ is connected, there is a circuit $C_3$ of $N$ such that $\{e,f\} \subseteq C_3$.  Thus, there is path of length $2$ between $C_1$ and $C_2$ in the intersection graph of circuits.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt I updated it, so basically these matroids are just the direct sum of connect matroids with partition matroids if I understand your answer

Comment: More precisely, they are the direct sum of a connected matroid with a free matroid (no circuits).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the question was edited while I typed. The second question I refer is when a matroid M has an ordering $C_1,\dots, C_n$ of its circuits such that for each $2\le i\le n$, there exists $j<i$ such that $C_i$ and $C_j$ intersect:

The questions are not equivalent. The answer to the second question (the one about the graph) is given by Tony Huynh: $M$ is connected except for coloops. This happens to be the answer to the first question too (the one about the circuit ordering).

We reduce the proof to the case that $M$ is coloopless. On one hand if $M$ has such an ordering for its circuits, then $M$ is connected by the answer for the other question.

The other implication is proved by induction on the number of elements. Suppose that $M$ is connected and smaller connected matroids than $M$ have such an ordering of its circuits. There is a result that says that $M$ has an element $e$ such that either $M\backslash e$ is connected or $e$ is in serial pair of $M$ and $M/e$ is connected. In the latter case, a desired ordering of the circuits of $M/e$ induces an ordering of the corresponding circuits in $M$. In the former case, one just has to add the circuits of $M$ containing $e$ to the end of a desired ordering of the circuits of $M\backslash e$.